# Heroku Node.js npm install failing suddenly

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, bots, cicd

I have never touched my `package.json` file for as long as my bot has been deployed and I've never had issues deploying my bot on Heroku...until today. Seemingly inexplicably, I'm suddenly getting the following error today when I try to deploy my bot — after having changed nothing about my `package.json` file and doing nothing to my Heroku cache.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  17.0.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.49.2
       
       Resolving node version 17.0.1...
       Downloading and installing node 17.0.1...
       Bootstrapping npm 8.49.2 (replacing 8.1.0)...
       Unable to install npm 8.49.2; does it exist?
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

On a hunch, based on the Stack Overflow article found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788988/unable-to-install-node-in-heroku), I ran the `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` command for my app, to no avail. I'm still encountering this issue and there appears to be no sign of any successful deployments any time soon.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup, as the error says, npm 8.49.2 doesn't exist. The latest 8.x release is currently [8.19.3](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.19.3). Where did you get the 8.49.2 version string? Did you mean to type 8.19.2?

Comment: Oof... Yeah, looks like that was a typo. Initially, the `package.json` file had `*` for the npm version, so I tried explicitly calling out the version I had installed on my machine to fix the issue...and fat-fingered a `4` instead of a `1`. Looks like it deployed successfully now. Thank you for that...

Answer (score 1):

Typos strike once again. I simply had an invalid version number specified when trying to explicitly call out a version of npm rather than `*`, fat-fingering a `4` instead of a `1`. Thanks go to Chris from the comment above.